# C# Form Doesn't Hide

Tags: c#, forms

I'm making an application and I have 2 forms. The main form (main application) and the login form, which will start up. If the user has an API key, it'll check, and if it's correct, it should hide the login form and show the main form. If it's incorrect or the user has no api key at all, it should keep showing the login form and if the login details are correct, it should hide the login form and show the main form.

If I login and my details are correct, the login window will be hidden and the main form will be shown, however, if I have an API key and it's correct, it doesn't hide the login form.

This is when my login details are correct:

```
case "True":
string apiToken = subparts[0];

RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Prtscreen");
key.SetValue("API_TOKEN", subparts[0]);
key.Close();

MessageBox.Show("Logged in as " + username.Text);

UserDetails.UserName = username.Text;
UserDetails.APIKey = subparts[0];

this.Hide();
new MainForm().Show();
break;
```

What happens: my details are correct, login window 'disappears' and main form shows. Now this is when I have an API key and it's correct:

```
UserDetails.UserName = result.Split('|')[1];
UserDetails.APIKey = value.ToString();

this.Hide();
Program.MainForm = new MainForm();
Program.MainForm.Show();

return true;
```

But for some reason, it doesn't hide the login window. Both of the codes are in the login form code file. I don't know what's so different.

Comment: Can you show us a bit more of the code, it is difficult to see what is going on here. We appear to be within a switch case statement?

Comment: It's only about showing and hiding the forms what is not working. Both of the codes above have the same code (for showing and hiding, well at least the hide) but for the second code it just doesn't hide the login form, while it does in the first code.

Comment: So why do you create the Show() code differently each time? There must be some significance of using Program. Also, is any of this taking place in Form_Load?

Comment: This is my full code: http://pastebin.com/4iptk1yB

Comment: You do realise that   //CheckAPI(); is commented out? The code isn't even being called as far as I can see.

Comment: Just to test some other code while I was waiting. It won't work even when I uncomment it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a form can change its visibility or call Show/Hide on itself in its own Load event. For a quick fix, you can use a timer to delay the check briefly until the form finishes loading. In the timer elapsed/tick event, that's where you would call your CheckAPI method.